# Fazer um SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela

Tags: php

Fazer um `(SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'imagem')`, pegar esse valor e passar como parâmetro numa função. Como faço?

```
<?php
    require("Configs/connection.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fotos do Casamento</title>

        <link href="css/sl-main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body onload="iniciaSlider("Colocar aqui o valor COUNT")">

        <div id="moldura"></div>
        <input id="abutton" type="button" value="Anterior"
onclick="troca(-1)"/>
        <input id="pbutton" type="button" value="Próximo" onclick="troca(1)"/>
        <div>
        <input id="vbutton" type="button" value="Voltar" onclick="voltar()"/>
        </div>
        <script src="js/sl-main.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pode dar mais informações? Você tem algum código?

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código completo por favor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu arquivo

```
<?php
    require("Configs/connection.php");
  $host = 'localhost'; // endereço do servidor de banco de dados.
    $dbname = 'tabela'; //nome de sua base de dados
    $user   = 'root'; // seu usuário do banco
    $pass   = 'senha'; // sua senha do banco
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname,$user,$pass);

    $lista = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) total from imagem') or trigger_error($pdo->error);
    $lista->execute();
    $item = $lista->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total = $item[0]['total'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fotos do Casamento</title>

        <link href="css/sl-main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body onload="iniciaSlider(<?php echo $total; ?>)">

        <div id="moldura"></div>
        <input id="abutton" type="button" value="Anterior"
onclick="troca(-1)"/>
        <input id="pbutton" type="button" value="Próximo" onclick="troca(1)"/>
        <div>
        <input id="vbutton" type="button" value="Voltar" onclick="voltar()"/>
        </div>
        <script src="js/sl-main.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vou testar, muito obrigado.

Comment: vai ter um errinho fácil de arrumar `"iniciaSlider("<?php echo $total; ?>")"` deveria ser `"iniciaSlider('<?php echo $total; ?>')"` ou `"iniciaSlider(<?php echo $total; ?>)"`

Comment: obrigado @VirgilioNovic corrigido ^^

Comment: Esta dando erro aqui "$lista = $db->prepare('SELECT count(*) total from imagem') or trigger_error($db->error);"=> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string

Comment: onde tiver escrito DB, troca por PDO => $lista = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) total from imagem') or trigger_error($pdo->error);

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço a atenção.